# How to restrict navigating to other page from a customer magento page

Tags: magento2, login, redirect, two-factor-authentication

I am working on a module that implements two **factor authentication**.

I have created an **observer** to the **event** `customer_login` , so just after when the  customer has logged in, they are **directed** to a **custom page** for the **two factor authentication**, if authentication is successful he is directed to the **home page**.

But the problem is when the customer is in the **custom page**, he could change the URL and get to the **home page**(ie. without completing the two factor authentication process). How do I restrict the customer from navigating to other pages without completing the two factor authentication?

Comment: you need to set that authentication key also into the session so that you can check for it otherwise it will not work try to understand that how to restrict the customer without login first & then create this feature

Comment: Thanks for the reply @ABHISHEKTRIPATHI I am new to magento, How do I restrict the customer login?